# Emailing about IP changes

Tags: unix, ip-address, ip, dynamic-ip

You can choose any language. I am interested to know the simplest solution. How can you get your comp's IP and email it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux bash command line:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1 | mail -s 'My IP address' someone@example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Awk alternative to unwind's solution:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}' | mail -s "My IP address" some@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a website doing this.
it will send the ip address to the email address you type in.
http://mmmip.com